# Odoo. I'd like to make invisible the record in tree view, depending value of one field

Tags: treeview, odoo, invisible

Openerp, Odoo question.
I'd like to hide the row in tree view depending one field (e.g. item is not in stock).

Maybe I need to put this somewhere in tree_view.xml:

attrs="{'invisible': [('in_stock','=', 0)]}"

It would be fine, if this works, like the res_partner 'Active' flag
When 'Active' field is False, all record is disappeared.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the record completely than use this domain in the window action. To show only the records that matches the domain.

```
       <field name="domain">[('in_stock', '=', 0)]</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide using the following syntax:

```
<field name="flag" invisible="1"/>
<field name="x" attrs="{'invisible': [('flag','=', False)]}"/>
```

Here flag should be a computed field which computes the stock of current item.
so in script just make the field as:

```
flag = fields.Boolean("String", compute="get_stock_status")

def get_stock_status(self):
    # do your computation and change values of flag accordingly
    self.flag = False
```